Is writing else statement at the last mandatory in if-else ladder in C++?
I have always seen that at the end of an if-else ladder in C++, the bottom else statement is always present.
if (condition1) {
  doA();
} else if (condition2) {
  doB();
} else if (condition3) {
  doC();
} else {
  noConditionsMet();
}

Is it necessary to do this syntax-wise? Or i can also write code as shown below i.e without using the last else statement ?
if (condition1) {
  doA();
} else if (condition2) {
  doB();
} else if (condition3) {
  doC();
}

I know that the below code also gets run successfully. But I just wanted to confirm by asking this in the forum.

An else clause is optional.

Yes, it's legal. In general, An if-else-if ladder is not a special case, it's just a bunch of if else where the braces after else are omitted. It's easier to see if you indent the code like this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hb8jddv9v

@Someprogrammerdude  So writing the code without the last '' else '' is also valid. Right ?

@DivyanshuDwivedi Both snippets are valid but they don't do the same thing. I'm confused about your question since you clearly understand that noConditionsMet() will not be called in the second snippet.

C++23 has std::unreachable. If it is mandatory that the final else branch never be taken, you can use that instead of noConditionMet(). In debug builds, it often behaves like assert(false), and in release builds, it is a signal to the optimizer to take advantage (if possible).

It's optional, and the "ladder" is an illusion.
The syntax of a conditional statement is
if (condition) 
    statement 
else 
    statement

where the else branch is optional.
Whether the else branch happens to be another conditional doesn't matter.
Note that your "ladder" is equivalent to
if (condition1) {
  doA();
} else {
    if (condition2) {
      doB();
    } else {
        if (condition3) {
            doC();
        } else {
            noConditionsMet();
        }
    }
}

which makes it clearer that it's not a "ladder", just nested statements.
It's just that you can leave out the "block braces" when a branch consists of a single statement.

So I can skip the last " else " clause ? Am i correct ? Yes ?

That is what "optional" means, yes.

The final else statement is not required, as you stated. But I usually include it to catch and handle cases where none of the preceding conditions are met.
For example, if there is a condition4 your code will scoot on past and might introduce bugs that make you pull out your hair in the future.  Up to you if it makes sense in the context you are using it.

No! The 'else' clause is completely optional!

you mean the " else " written at the last in else-if ladder is optional ? Right ?
